# Using Angular ngmodel without name attribute

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

I am just reading and learning Angular2 tutorial. [Here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html#!#ngModel) it says "Defining a name attribute is a requirement when using [(ngModel)] in combination with a form."
However, in the tutorial, it is using ngmodel without a name attribute [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html).

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="name"/>
```

Could you please explain why this is working? 
Please note : I am new to angular as well as UI

Comment: you have answered your own question, if you read carefully it says Defining a name attribute is a requirement when using [(ngModel)] in **combination with a form**. in the example discussed it does not uses a Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe that in your first link [**HERE**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html) they aren't using a `<form></form>` element.

Because in your 2nd link [**HERE**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html#!#ngModel) they say

```
Defining a name attribute is a requirement when using [(ngModel)] in combination with a form.
```

**... in combination with a form**. In their [conclusion](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html#!#conclusion) files, `hero-form.component.html` they have a `<form>` wrapped around the input with the name attribute.

Now I don't know why the `<form></form>` element makes a difference on why you need the `name` attribute **but** that is why your code is working, because in your first link and in your example there isn't a form around the element.

Good question though, I just learned that, thanks to you having me look it up!

Comment: I would suggest HERE since it makes more sens. However if we pick the HERE one we may face some performance issues